# Profiles in pom.xml maven

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, pom.xml, allure

here is my pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
      <dependencies>
        ... dependencies ...
     </dependencies>

 <profiles> 
        <profile>
            <id>suit1</id>
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                  <property>
                        <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                    </property>
                <argLine>   -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.1/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar" </argLine>
                <suiteXmlFiles>      <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/Smartphones/suite1.xml</suiteXmlFile>                  </suiteXmlFiles>

            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
       <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

    </profile>
</profiles> 
</project>
```

I want to have many profiles here. In which of them I'm going to add new suite(number).xml

Is it possible to left only this:

```
<suiteXmlFiles>   
   <suiteXmlFile>
               src/test/java/Smartphones/suite1.xml
    </suiteXmlFile> 
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

in the profile section? And do not copy plugins and dependencies in each profile? Is it possible to move this information above? What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you need suite1.xml files? Usually you will run all unit test ? Or do I misunderstand a thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything's possible!

What you should do is this:

- Define your `<build/>` section in the root of the `pom.xml` (not in a `<profile/>`).
- Define your `<plugin/>` in this section. Don't define a `<configuration/>`, just have the `<groupId/>`, `<artifactId/>` and `<version/>`, or if you do define a `<configuration/>`, make sure it's not for the things that you'd like to have extracted to a `<profile/>`, (for example, don't put your `<suiteXmlFiles/>` section there).
- In your `<profiles>` define the different configuration settings that would be specific just to your `<profile/>`.

Consider the following example:

```
<project ....>
    ...

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <!-- pluginManagement is used to define the configuration
                 of your plugins and then inherit it
                 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                    </property>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.1/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar"</argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- When there is a pluginManagement section like the one above,
                 you can just invoke your plugins like without
                 any further configuration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles> 
        <profile>
            <!-- So, since you're now inheriting from the
                 pluginManagement section and you've declared that
                 your project uses these plugins, you can now extract
                 the suite configuration in a separate profile like this:
                 -->
            <id>suite1</id>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>      

       <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/Smartphones/suite1.xml</suiteXmlFile>                  
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: That worked,  the only thing needed was to add `<plugins>` tag under `<pluginManagement>` otherwise it threw an error

Answer (score 0):

A `profile` is something that you add on top of the plain `pom`, so you should put in your `profile` only what you want to change.

In your case you could move the `maven-compiler-plugin` and maybe the `allure-maven` in the main `pom` and duplicate only the `surefire` setup.
You might also try to move the dependencies of `surefire` in the `pluginManagement` section of the main `pom`.

If, for some reason, you cannot move those configuration in the main `pom`, you can define a profile common with all those configuration and add a specific profile for each `suite.xml`.

In that case you will need to enable two profiles for each execution, the common and the suite.